# Accepting and returning java.time in my controller

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring-boot, java-8

While using spring-boot I'm trying to use java.time in my controller. More specifically I'm trying to make LocalDate javascript friendly. By friendly I mean outputting it in a format javascript can parse and also making my controller accept the data posted (or put... or patch'ed) from angular (or the like).

My entity looks like the following:

```
@Entity
public class Expense {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    ...
    private LocalDate date;

    public Expense() {
    }

    public LocalDate getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(final LocalDate date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    ...
}
```

My controller looks like the following:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ExpenseController {
    @Autowired
    private ExpenseService service;

    @RequestMapping("/expense")
    public Iterable<Expense> findAll() {
        return service.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/expense", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Expense save(@RequestBody Expense expense) {
        return service.save(expense);
    }
    ...
}
```

I've added the below to my pom file. Which causes the LocalDate to be return as a list of [yyyy, mm, dd] but javascript doesn't like that. And it still doesn't accept the format posted from the browser.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

What I'm basically looking for is a way to return java.time types in javascript friendly formats and also be able to receive them when I'm posting to my controller.

I've seen that @DateTimeFormat is used in lots of places, as well as @JsonFormat, but I couldn't get it to work probably. Also I'm looking for a way to globally handle this.

Can anyone give me some information about how to do this?

The complete code can be found at https://github.com/tonsV2/MyBiz

Update:
I've tried adding the following bean to my @SpringBootApplication class.

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, true);
    return mapper;
}
```

Comment: No idea if this can help but there is an option that you can apply to your `ObjectMapper`: `om.configure(WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, true/false);`.

Comment: @assylias - I couldn't get it to work. I've created a bean and added it to my Application class... that's how it's done, right? I've updated my question to show what I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this should fix the problem

```
@Bean
public Module getLocalDateModule() {
    SimpleModule sm = new SimpleModule("LocalDateModule");
    sm.addSerializer(LocalDate.class, new JsonSerializer<LocalDate>() {
        @Override
        public void serialize(LocalDate localDate, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            jsonGenerator.writeString(localDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'00:00:00.000'Z'")));
        }
    });
    return sm;
}
```

The JSR310 thing probably does not work because
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310

> LocalDate, LocalTime, LocalDateTime, and OffsetTime, which cannot
>   portably be converted to timestamps and are instead represented as
>   arrays when WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS is enabled.